# Serie de Fibonacci usando punteros

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
using namespace std;
int cont;
int x=0;
int y=1;
int *Fibonacci(int*, int*);
```

Así es como estoy declarando las variables y el puntero

```
int *Fibonacci(int*, int*)
{
    int * r=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(cont=1;cont<=10;cont++){
    * r=x+y;
        x=y;
        y=*r;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    system("cls");
    cout<<"La Serie de Fibonacci de 10 dijitos es: "<<*Fibonacci<<endl;
    system("pause>>cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Tengo un problema con mi código, ya que solo necesito imprimir los primeros 10 dígitos de la serie de Fibonacci, el código cuando lo corro no me saca ningún error funciona al parecer bien, cuando aparece en pantalla solo me arroja un 1.

[image: Esto es lo que pasa cuando corro es programa]

Comment: Algunas observaciones: `1.-` tu función Fibonacci está declarada para recibir 2 punteros de tipo `int` y cuando la invocas no le envías esos parámetros. `2.-` la variable `cont` que está dentro de el `for` de tu función Fibonacci debería tener un tipo de dato, en este caso de tipo `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de lo comentado por [@PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/287414/463), la función tiene varios problemas:

**Argumentos sin uso**

No tiene sentido que la función acepte dos argumentos si los mismos no se van a usar nunca. La claridad del código en C++ no debe ser subestimada en ningún caso:

```
int *Fibonacci(int*, int*)
//             ^^^^  ^^^^
```

**Memoria dinámica**

Salvo que pretendas que la función devuelva una lista de valores, no tiene sentido que use memoria dinámica. La memoria dinámica es complicada de gestionar y suele ser el origen de muchísimos errores... así que es preferible usarla solo cuando es realmente necesario:

```
int Fibonacci(int*, int*)
{
    int r=0;
    for(cont=1;cont<=10;cont++)
    {
        r=x+y;
        x=y;
        y=r;
    }
    return r;
}
```

**Secuencia incorrecta**

La función, tal cual está escrita. Únicamente será capaz de devolverte un número, concretamente el 89. Si revisamos la sucesión:

```
posición  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13
valor      0   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144
                                                      ^^
```

Vemos que estás devolviendo el 12º número...

**Variables globales**

Te sugiero que no uses variables globales mientras no sea realmente necesario. Las variables globales son otra fuente de errores por varios motivos:

- Su ciclo de vida es particular. La vida nos enseña a reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible. Tener por defecto variables cuya vida es equivalente a la del programa es, por tanto, una pésima idea.
- Acceso sin restricciones. Cualquier función o proceso puede leer y modificar las variables globales a discrección. Conforme el programa crece en tamaño y complejidad esto empieza a ser un problema... y depurarlo no es precisamente sencillo
- Gestión de recursos. Un objeto global mal utilizado (o si se produce una excepción) puede dejar un recurso del sistema bloqueado durante muchísimo tiempo. Los objetos locales no suelen tener ese problema.
- ...

**Los bucles empiezan en 0**

En programación, los bucles se usan sobretodo para recorrer listas de elementos. En C++, estas listas tienen el primer elemento bajo el índice 0.

Así pues lo habitual es que los bucles empiecen en 0. Cuando ya llevas un tiempo programando será más natural interpretar este bucle:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
```

que este otro:

```
for( int i=1; i<=10; i++)
```

Pese a que ambos implican 10 iteraciones.

Así que, lo dicho, no uses variables globales.

**Resumen**

Bueno, si juntamos todo lo comentado nos quedan dos posibilidades:

1. La función devuelve una lista con la secuencia de números solicitada

   En el primer caso es necesario usar memoria dinámica ya que la cantidad de números a devolver solo se conoce en tiempo de ejecución (ahora son 10, pero en el futuro podría ser cualquier otro número).

   Una posible aproximación:

   ```
   int* Fibonacci(int numeros)
   {
     int* r= new int[numeros];
     r[0] = 0;
     if( numeros > 1 )
     {
       r[1] = 1;
       int index=2;
       numeros--;

       int x=0, y=1;
       for(int i=0;i<numeros;i++, index++)
       {
         r[index]=x+y;
         x=y;
         y=r[index];
       }
     }
     return r;
   }

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       std::cout<<"La Serie de Fibonacci de 10 digitos es: ";

       int* numeros = Fibonacci(10);
       for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
       {
           if( i != 0 ) std::cout << ", ";
           std::cout << numeros[i];
       }

       delete[] numeros;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. La función devuelve únicamente un número (es necesario llamarla varias veces)

   Aunque alguno se pondrá quisquilloso diciendo que esta solución *no es óptima*, lo cierto es que resulta mucho más sencilla, ya que no necesitamos usar memoria dinámica. Además, el incremento en el tiempo de ejecución es despreciable a la hora de calcular los primeros 10 números.

   ```
   int Fibonacci(int index)
   {
     if( index < 2 )
         return index; // 0 y 1

     index--;
     int r;
     int x=0, y=1;
     for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
     {
       r=x+y;
       x=y;
       y=r;
     }
     return r;
   }

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       std::cout<<"La Serie de Fibonacci de 10 digitos es: ";

       for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
       {
           if( i != 0 ) std::cout << ", ";
           std::cout << Fibonacci(i);
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problema.

> El código cuando lo corro no me saca ningún error funciona al parecer bien, cuando aparece en pantalla solo me arroja un 1.

El problema que describes es reproducible con este sencillo código:

```
void x() {}

int main {
    std::cout << *x;
    return 0;
}
```

Cuya salida es: `1`.

---

En C++ el nombre de una función libre (una función que no pertenece a un objeto) es equivalente al puntero a una función de ese tipo; usando el operador de des-referencia (el `*` unario) obtienes una referencia a una función de ese tipo:

```
int main {
    std::cout << *x;
//               ~~ <--- void(&)();
    return 0;
}
```

Ninguna de las [sobrecargas del operador de inyección del flujo de salida de datos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) (*out stream*) acepta referencias a funciones, pero una referencia a función se puede convertir implícitamente a puntero a función, y un puntero se puede convertir implícitamente a booleano, y un booleano cuyo valor sea diferente a cero será `true`, y sacar `true` por consola muestra `1`. Si añades `std::boolalpha` al código verás que estás en realidad imprimiendo un booleano:

```
void x() {}

int main()     {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << *x;
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior tiene como salida: `true`. Tu código tiene el mismo problema que el ejemplo reducido que te he mostrado, no estás llamando a la función: estás imprimiendo el puntero a la función como booleano:

```
cout<<"La Serie de Fibonacci de 10 dijitos es: "<<*Fibonacci<<endl;
//                     int *(&)(int *, int *) --> ~~~~~~~~~~
```

#### Errores.

Tu código tiene varios errores conceptuales y de diseño. El más evidente es que (como se menciona en el apartado anterior) no llamas a la función, seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int a = 0, b = 0;
//      ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Variables que la función necesita.

    std::cout << 
        "La Serie de Fibonacci de 10 dijitos es: " <<
        *Fibonacci(&a, &b) << endl;
//                 ~~~~~~ <-- Llamar a la función CON las variables.

    return 0;
}
```

Además estás reservando memoria dentro de la función, pero nunca la liberas, deberías hacer esto:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    int *r = Fibonacci(&a, &b);

    std::cout << "La Serie de Fibonacci de 10 dijitos es: " << *r << endl;
    free(r);
//  ~~~~~~~ <-- Liberar la memoria solicitada DENTRO de la función.

    return 0;
}
```

Pero esta aproximación esta muy alejada de las recomendaciones del C++ moderno, en primer lugar porque la pareja `malloc`/`free` pertenecen a C, en C++ se usa la pareja `new`/`delete`. En segundo lugar porque nunca, NUNCA, **NUNCA** se debe reservar memoria dentro de una función y desentenderse de dicha memoria; mejor usa un puntero inteligente:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> Fibonacci(int *x, int *y)
// DEBES dar nombre ----------->    ~       ~
// a las variables si quieres usarlas!
{
    auto r = std::make_unique<int>();

    for (int cont = 1; cont <= 10; cont++) {
//       ~~~ <-- ¡Las variables DEBEN tener tipo!
        *r= *x + *y;
//          ~~   ~~ <-- Las variables son punteros DEBES des-referenciarlas.
        *x = *y;
//      ~~   ~~ <-- Las variables son punteros DEBES des-referenciarlas.
        *y = *r;
//      ~~   ~~ <-- Las variables son punteros DEBES des-referenciarlas.
    }

    return r;
}
```

Además del error de la memoria, estabas tratando a los punteros como valores, lo cuál haría que tu código no se comportase de la manera esperada… para evitar este tipo de problemas debes seguir la [correctitud de constantes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctitud_de_constantes), que viene a decir que todo valor que no deba ser modificado **debe** ser `const`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> Fibonacci(int *const x, int *const y)
// El lugar apuntado NO cambia -->  ~~~~~         ~~~~~
{
    auto r = std::make_unique<int>();

    for (int cont = 1; cont <= 10; cont++) {
        *r= *x + *y;
        *x = *y;
        *y = *r;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Por último, [favorece el pre-incremento frente al post-incremento](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/), y acostúmbrate a indexar desde 0 en lugar de desde 1, con estas correcciones tu código podría parecerse a:

#### Propuesta.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SP21dJjh4hnGoReH):
    #include 
    #include

```
std::unique_ptr<int> Fibonacci(int *const x, int *const y)
{
    auto r = std::make_unique<int>();

    for (int cont = 0; cont < 10; ++cont) {
        *r= *x + *y;
        *x = *y;
        *y = *r;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    std::cout << *Fibonacci(&a, &b);

    return 0;
}
```